# Expression Engine using minimee vs using a CDN for assets

Tags: expressionengine, cdn, assets, minify, content-delivery-network

I am deploying an expression engine install and am trying to optimize the delivery of static assets as much as possible. What would likely be the better solution?

-Using Minimee to minify and concatinate css/js/html and deliver from the main server

OR

-Using a CDN like amazon cloudfront and doing the minification/gzip on that end and only serving static assets in this way?

OR

-some combination of both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd definitely consider using **Amazon Cloudfront** as a CND first and then do additional minification as needed. I think that serving assets via a CND will give you bigger boost in performance than just minification.

Additionally, [**Assets plugin**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) for **Expression Engine** has a built-in  **Amazon S3** support so it could make syncing your assets with seamless. Alternatively, you could `rsync` periodically, that works well too; I have used [**s3cmd tool**](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) in the last it works well (don't get turned off by the look of their website, **s3cmd** is very easy to use.